# Mongodb $or query optimization index

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have a query. It seems that the index does not work. The query takes more than 7 seconds

My model

```js
const likeSchema = new Schema({

    user: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    wind: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Wind'},
    windUser: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},

    comment: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'Comment'},
    commentUser: {type: ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
    
    type: {type: Number, default: 0},
    read: {type: Boolean, default: false},
    datetime: {type: Date, default: Date.now}

}, {strict: false})


likeSchema.index({windUser: 1, commentUser: 1 })
```

query criteria

```js
let filter = { $or:[{ windUser: user }, { commentUser: user }] }
```

Is there a problem with my index? Is this or query, index building correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As documented [here](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/or/#-or-clauses-and-indexes), you need two indexes:

```
likeSchema.index({ windUser: 1 })
likeSchema.index({ commentUser: 1 })
```

Databases are not able to efficiently use a single compound index to process a query with an `OR`. While the compound index you've mentioned would help with a filter against the `windUser` field, it is not very helpful for `commentUser` by itself. Since the operator is a `$or` rather than a `$and` the database cannot combine both of the bounds at the same time since it would miss results.

*Edit* Also worth mentioning that questions like this are best understood by gathering and looking at `explain` output. You should see that with the current configuration that the database chooses to do a collection scan rather than use the compound index that is currently present.

Comment: The answer is effective. Thank you very much. The document link is also very useful. I need to learn more.

Comment: I have a query `let filter = {_id: searchRecord, user: user}`. What about indexing? I know there is a default `_id` index, do I need `index({_id: 1, user: 1})`?

Comment: That feels like a different topic (no `$or` involved) which would be better served with a new question? That query can return at most one document (since `_id` is `unique`), so probably no need for another index

Comment: Yes, we need to start a new Q&A. Your reply is very good, and your thinking is very good. Thank you very much